# Camel-sql header CamelSqlRowCount is not overriden for multiple queries

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I use a sql endpoint to run a query from camel.
But when i call a second the CamelSqlRowCount isn't changed:

```
@Component
public class TestSQLRowCount  extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://testsql?fixedRate=true&period=5000")
            .to("sql:select 1 from dual_seq?dataSource=#dataSource&outputHeader=TEST_ROW_COUNT&outputType=SelectOne")
            .log("OLD_AUDIT_DATA ${headers.TEST_ROW_COUNT} - ROW_COUNT ${headers.CamelSqlRowCount}")
            .to("sql:select 1 from dual_seq where 0 = 1?dataSource=#dataSource&outputHeader=TEST_ROW_COUNT2&outputType=SelectOne")
            .log("OLD_AUDIT_DATA ${headers.TEST_ROW_COUNT2} - ROW_COUNT ${headers.CamelSqlRowCount}")
            .end();
    }
}
```

Output:
2021-12-01 14:20:02.880  INFO OLD_AUDIT_DATA 1 - ROW_COUNT 1
2021-12-01 14:20:02.944  INFO OLD_AUDIT_DATA  - ROW_COUNT 1

When i switch the statements:

```
@Component
public class TestSQLRowCount  extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://testsql?fixedRate=true&period=5000")
            .to("sql:select 1 from dual_seq where 0 = 1?dataSource=#dataSource&outputHeader=TEST_ROW_COUNT2&outputType=SelectOne")
            .log("OLD_AUDIT_DATA ${headers.TEST_ROW_COUNT2} - ROW_COUNT ${headers.CamelSqlRowCount}")
            .to("sql:select 1 from dual_seq?dataSource=#dataSource&outputHeader=TEST_ROW_COUNT&outputType=SelectOne")
            .log("OLD_AUDIT_DATA ${headers.TEST_ROW_COUNT} - ROW_COUNT ${headers.CamelSqlRowCount}")
            .end();
    }
}
```

Output:
2021-12-01 14:22:25.021  INFO OLD_AUDIT_DATA  - ROW_COUNT 0
2021-12-01 14:22:25.076  INFO OLD_AUDIT_DATA 1 - ROW_COUNT 0

How can I reset the header ?

Thanks in advance

Bart

Comment: insert `.removeHeader("CamelSqlRowCount")`just before the second query  ?

Comment: Thx, That does seem to solve the issue. But the code used to work correctly. The issue appeared to have popped up after we upgraded to camel 3.11.2

<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>